# Expresión contraria a "caso de éxito"

Tags: solicitud-de-término, antónimos

Quisiera saber: **¿Cuál es la expresión contraria a la frase "caso de éxito"?**

"Caso de éxito" se dice cuando la implementación de una nueva tecnología ha dado frutos en una organización, haciendo de ésta un entorno más eficiente.

Así también se puede usar para comunidades en las que una idea, una campaña o una iniciativa ha mejorado la vida de las personas.

Pero, ¿cuál es la palabra referente a un caso de éxito cuya implementación no dio el mismo fruto, o sus resultados no fueron los esperados?

He buscado diferentes antónimos de la palabra "éxito" (fracaso, revés, caída) pero, al unirlos con la frase "caso de..." los resultados son nulos.

Comment: Quizá no exista una frase hecha del mismo estilo. A fin de cuentas el éxito es excepcional, el fracaso o los resultados mediocres son la norma. ¿"Fiasco" quizá?

Comment: Cuando el resultado es negativo, se lo suele enmascarar con el eufemismo "lección aprendida". Hablariamos entonces de "casos de éxito y lecciones aprendidas".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se suele usar el término "historia de fracaso" o incluso "caso de fracaso", pero no creo que se use como un vocablo establecido. Más bien se usa "historia" porque suelen ser una breve descripción de acontecimientos para aprender de esos errores. El uso de "fracaso" es obvio. Es el antónimo directo de "exento".

A veces se usa con el alcance que tendría un caso de éxito (es decir, algo que intentó una compañía y no le salió bien) y otras veces con el sentido más amplio de compañías que dejaron de existir.

Este [*slideshare*](https://www.slideshare.net/rubenpd/los-10-mayores-fracasos-empresariales-de-la-historia) de LinkedIn ofrece algunos ejemplos de ambos (McDonald's tiene una historia de fracaso vendiendo *Mc Spaghetti* pero la empresa sigue. Por otro lado, *Betamáx* tiene una historia de fracaso empresarial que refleja que la empresa dejó de existir al no saber hacer frente a un rival).

Este otro artículo de [MuyPymes](http://www.muypymes.com/2011/08/23/historias-fracasos-empresiales)  no lo dice explícitamente, pero llama a estas historias "casos empresariales (de fracaso)":

> Para hacer este repaso a algunos de los **casos empresariales** [de fracaso] que peor suerte tuvieron hemos diferentes compañías de diversos sectores que cometieron en su momento errores de diferente calado

Como dice Gustavson en los comentarios a veces se usa el término "[lección aprendida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lessons_learned)", aunque este último se puede usar tanto para algo positivo (qué conocimiento hemos ganado al desarrollar este prototipo) como negativo (hemos aprendido lo que no hay que hacer). Este término refleja más algo que se comparte dentro de la propia institución.

Answer (score 2):

En el mundo de los negocios, donde todo se trata de poner de forma positiva, creo que la contraparte de un "Caso de Éxito" es una "Área de Oportunidad".

Se utiliza la frase "Área de Oportunidad" para demostrar un ejemplo en el que las cosas no funcionaron de la mejor forma por lo que se puede mejorar lo que se hizo.